# Performance of SQL query if more conditions includes in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

Can anyone answer how the performance of SQL will be impacted if we include more conditions in `Where` clause?

For example I have a table `TABLE1` with 15 columns `Column1`, `Column2`, ..., `Column15`. And of those 15 columns, `column1` (primary key) and `column7` are indexed.

Now if I want to retrieve the data based on `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN7` and `COLUMN10` from my application (hibernate ORM), so is it good to query with

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN1 = ? AND COLUMN7 = ? AND COLUMN10 = ?
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN1 = ? AND COLUMN7 = ?
```

and filter the results for `COLUMN10` in the application side?

Including more filters in the `WHERE` clause gives better performance or it is bad for performance of SQL query?

Comment: There are other considerations.  Bringing too much data to the application could cause server RAM problems.

Comment: Check the execution plan

Answer (score 2):

You should put more conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  Let the database do the work.  Here are two good reasons:

- It reduces the amount of data passing between the database and the application.  Less data is more performance.
- It allows the database to optimize the query, perhaps using better indexes.  More optimization is more performance.